# "Say for someone to do something" in colloquial AE

Tags: word-usage, colloquialisms

In colloquial prose, is the idiomatic "say for" an appropriate substitute for "tell" in "tell someone to do something" whatever the context?

E.g.

> Have I ever said for you to pretend to be someone you are not. <sub>[source](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1JPd3X-iNxEC&pg=PA200&lpg=PA200&dq=%22have+i+ever+said+for+you+to%22&source=bl&ots=21eV5O5zv3&sig=IkKMB7PIy3mlEim9A9CYVpP-u78&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=VbYQU4SoHoOshQfE1ICoDA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22have%20i%20ever%20said%20for%20you%20to%22&f=false)</sub>
>
> We concluded the conversation with my saying for him to contact me in six months.<sub>[source](http://books.google.com.br/books?id=xoacDfRqsdwC&pg=PA77&lpg=PA77&dq=%22my+saying+for+him+to%22&source=bl&ots=8XfLWvbjk5&sig=E_6feawOTEbmEBPf04DQSSdkt9M&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ei=0gQRU8rdO4Tw0gXzqYDIBA&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22my%20saying%20for%20him%20to%22&f=false)</sub>
>
> Now I am saying for you to sit down...<sub>[source](http://www.angelfire.com/mn2/jwerp/fun/GM.html)</sub>
>
> May I say for you to call... <sub>[source](https://community.bt.com/t5/ADSL-Copper-Broadband-Speed/Hub-problems/td-p/97947)</sub>
>
> We parted with her saying for me to be safe.  [source](http://linda-musingsfrommyheart.blogspot.fr/2012_03_01_archive.html)
>
> Didn't you say for him to call his probation officer and tell him he was terminated? [source](http://law.justia.com/cases/texas/fifth-court-of-appeals/2010/05-09-00418-cr-5.html)
>
> I think he might be saying for us to reach out to Muslims... [source](http://news.blogs.cnn.com/2010/09/08/live-blog-imam-behind-nyc-islamic-center-speaks/comment-page-16/)
>
> I never said for him to rot in hell, that is God's decision after death. [source](http://whnt.com/2013/12/11/acklin-hearing-defense-witness-signals-numerous-red-flags/)

It sounds like what is meant in the last example is something like "I never wished for him to rot in hell" or "I never said he should rot in hell" rather than "I never told him to."

Does this sort of more obscure meaning of "say for" have any currency in colloquial speech and writing?

Comment: I suspect you're right about the colloquial usage (in the UK at least, and, I'd guess, to a _greater_ degree in the US). I'd add that the usage seems to be confined to interrogative and negative contexts (as in your examples). Sadly, there seem to be no examples on Google! I don't know why.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the references. Examples seem very rare! The first is a tramslation from Portuguese, and may be overly 'word-for-word'. The second might be evasion by a Lawyer, not wanting to be as direct as 'Didn't you tell him to ...' or as weak as 'Didn't you suggest that he ...'. Setting up the - defendant? -  by unconventional terminology!

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The first example is not a translation from Portuguese. The thing is I formatted my computer in Brazilian Portuguese for some reason.;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage is perfectly common and natural *in colloquial speech* for many people, but it wouldn't be considered acceptable in more formal contexts. It's certainly no more AmE than BrE.

Generally, *to say for [pro]noun to [do or be something]* implies ***call*** for them to do/be [whatever]. Thus it can't always be assumed that ***tell*** is a valid substitution. OP's final construction is more likely to be used where the speaker is claiming he never said *"I hope **he** rots in hell"* (spoken to a third party), rather than *"I hope **you** rot in hell"* (words addressed *to* "him").

Even in OP's first two examples, it's quite possible the speaker means he never *suggested to anyone else* that *you/he* should disguise your true self/call his probation officer. Only the precise context might make this clear - but personally, if it *didn't*, my inclination would be to favour the *told other people* interpretation.

Comment: _For ... to_ is the full infinitive complementizer. _For_ introduces the subject of the infinitive clause, and _to_ introduces the infinitive verb. Both may be deleted, under certain circumstances, and _for_ normally is deleted under most circumstances. The only place _for_ is really required is when an infinitive clause with a subject starts the sentence: _For Bill to leave now would be a bad idea_ vs **Bill to leave now would be a bad idea.*

Comment: @John: Ah, right. That clarifies for me what I hadn't quite managed to articulate above. When it occurs as *say **for X to***, this does *not* significantly imply saying anything *to X* (X connects forward to the infinitive clause following, not back to "say"). It can't possibly connect backwards in, for example, [*They didn't say for **it** to be within the four walls; maybe they'd have to go out somewhere.*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22within+the+four+walls+maybe+they'd+have+to%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry, what does "_It's certainly no more AmE than BrE._" mean? Thanks.

Comment: *Z is no more X than Y* is an alternative to *Z is as much Y as it is X*. That's used when refuting the prior claim that Z is *predominantly* X (if the prior claim had been that *Z is predominantly **Y***, the positions of X and Y would be reversed in both versions, when refuting the claim).

Answer (score 2):

Tell seems good here.

> Have I ever **told** you to pretend to be someone you are not.
>
> Didn't you **tell** him to call his probation officer and tell him he
>   was terminated?
>
> I never **told** him to rot in hell.